# rendering UIImage with size > 1024 with OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, uiimage, rendering

I'm capturing a full resolution UIImage on the iPhone 4 (1936X2592)
then i'm scaling it to a square of size 1936x1936.

now i need to load this image into a texture and let OpenGL render it with some GLSL.

problem is OpenGL only supports power of 2 texture sizes and only up to 1024.

so how do i solve this?

Thank You.

EDIT: my question is irrelevant, i target 3GS and up and it supports 2048x2048 image size.
my problem is another question: [Camera frame to UIImage to OpenGL rendering gives an odd image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068463/camera-frame-to-uiimage-to-opengl-rendering-gives-an-odd-image-attached)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the 3GS onwards, OpenGL supports textures up to 2048x2048. The 4S and iPad2 support 4096x4096.

However, if that weren't the case then your options revolve around packing pixels together with lossy compression or using multiple textures, both of which you can fix (at a cost) in your GLSL or via geometry.

The most obvious option is to upload as four tiles. Your output size of 1936 in each direction allows you to upload the textures with some overlap so that you should be able to get a seamless join even with linear texture filtering. Supposing you had only to split horizontally, you could ensure that the bottom two rows of one texture were the same as the top two rows of the other and put the geometry join between those two rows.

The other options are not only less obvious but also less useful. In terms of lossy packing, you might translate your texture from RGB to YUV space and in the 32 bits representing each RGBA sample store four 5 bit Y samples, one 6 bit U sample and one 6 bit V sample. You'd then unpack and recombine in the shader. However you'd get reduced visual quality and greatly reduced performance.

Comment: My app supports 3GS and up so it solves this issue, but OpenGL only supports power of 2 textures and 1936 not. so how i go about it?

Comment: Can you pad to 2048 (or, use `glTexImage2D` with a NULL data pointer to create a 2048x2048 texture then `glTexSubImage2D` with your actual data so that GL does the work for you) and then supply texture coordinates appropriately to use only 1936 pixels worth of the texture?

Answer (score 1):

Given the iPhone 4 only has a 960x640 screen why not just bring it down to 1024x1024?  This way you don't waste memory needlessly.

Failing that, split it into 4 textures.

Edit:  You don't actually have to destroy the original image when you draw 4 more.

As for splitting an image into 4 seperate UIImages its pretty easy.  To render the top left 1024x1024 into a UIImage you could do the following.

```
subImageArea = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 1024, 1024 );
CGImage* pCGSubImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( [pUILargeImage CGImage], subImageArea );
UIImage* pUISubImage = [UIImage initWithCGImage: pCGSubImage];
```

Comment: I want the full resolution rendered image to be saved in the iPhone's camera roll.  Can you elaborate on how to split a UIImage into multiple textures?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in your previous answers you can live with a texture size of 2048x2048.

I had a similar problem when doing screenshots, screen size 960x640 -> 1024x1024 Texture size, I simply do this:

```
void *buffer = malloc( x * y * 4 );

glReadPixels(0,0,x,y,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(1, &screenShotTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenShotTexture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, x, y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
free(buffer);
```

Of course I make sure x and y are POT.
I also had to fidle with the texture map, like this:

```
static const float screenTexCoordsR[] = {
0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.9375,
0.625, 0.0,
0.625, 0.9375
};
```

Yours would be not quite so wastefull, instead of 0.9375 and 0.625 you would have 0.9453 or something.

Comment: I don't understand how you're reading the fbo pixels into buffer before you put anything there.

Comment: In my case i'm reading directly with glReadPixels, but you probably need to memcopy to it from the uiimage data.