# Camera frame to UIImage to OpenGL rendering gives an odd image

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, uiimage

[image: before]

[image: after]

I'm extracting a UIImage with

`NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];`

then i'm creating an OpenGL texture and render it.
then i extract a UIImage from the frame buffer but it comes out wrong as you can see.

i tried playing with texture vertices array but it stayed the same.

this are the coordinates:

```
const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
-1.0f, -1.0f,
1.0f, -1.0f,
-1.0f,  1.0f,
1.0f,  1.0f,
};


const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f,  1.0f,
0.0f,  0.0f,
};


 glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);`
```

Comment: Show us the code. I'm guessing a texture coordinate problem...

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f` for your texture coordinates... could you try? And I assume you're drawing 2 triangles? What are the indices you're using?

Comment: i replaced glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); with glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 2); and it worked

Comment: strange thing though when applying a shader, when using parameter 4 it works but the image is as above, but when using 2 - the image is good but there is no shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem with your texture coordinates. Check them properly.